# how to scrape data from javascript website using python

Tags: python, json, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am unable to scrape data from website I have a URL link https://autodesk.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/Ext/0/refreshFacet/318c8bb6f553100021d223d9780d30be
when I open this link there are lots of job list showing when I scroll the page its automatic load the more job list when I inspect the page there are only JavaScript showing and I need to extract the following data job location, job description, job URL, full time or part time, minimum qualifications in json format I don't have idea how to do that below here my code

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from datetime import datetime
startTime = datetime.now()
import time
print('startTime',startTime)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\\Users\\arif khan\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://autodesk.wd1.myworkdayjobs.com/Ext/0/refreshFacet/318c8bb6f553100021d223d9780d30be')
```

Comment: well your code really does nothing just opens up the website

Comment: i don't understand what can i do next please do something

Comment: from what I saw you will have to access options? in tags like `title=`

Comment: but i can not find the element when i inspect the page

Comment: well I could but anyways from what I saw you have to access element's options like `title=` if you cannot access them with selenium it may be that there is an element in front of them that is hiding the below element and I think someone already had questions about that

Comment: sir please can you do for me cos i am new in python that is my interview task

Comment: I cannot do it for you because I dont know how, im not practising selenium but I have had experience with it

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract it from the div:

```
jobs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='WNOO WBOO']/ul/li")
for job in jobs:
    print(job)
```

While on the website, right-click and use "Inspect Element" to see the code for any specific element. For example, if you right click on the text "Finance Manager", and click "Inspect Element", it will reveal the code for it.